# Creating own throttle function and testing with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, timeout, throttling

I have an assignment to write my own throttle function. It needs to pass a certain amount of tests using setTimeout.

This is my code:

```
var throttle = function(func, delay) {
  var counter = 0;
  var calledOnce = false;
  setInterval(function(){
    counter++;
  }, 1);
  return function() {
    if (counter > delay || !calledOnce) {
      calledOnce = true;
      counter = 0; 
      return func.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  };
};
```

I am testing it with the following:

```
var callBack = function () {
  console.log('called');
};

var func = throttle(callback, 1000);

func();                     // should be called
setTimeout(func, 500);      // should not be called
setTimeout(func, 1000);     // should be called
setTimeout(func, 1500);     // should not be called
setTimeout(func, 1900);     // should not be called
```

However, when I run my code just how it is here, the function is only invoked once, with the original func() call, and none of the functions inside of a setTimeout are being invoked.

Is there any obvious problems with my code or testing using setTimeout?

Comment: You call only one time throttle and it set `calledOnce = true;` so the next func call refere to the same called throttle so they do nothing !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What is the problem in your code:

1. **setInterval** is computationally heavy compared to **setTimeout**.
2. your tests run on single thread will that be the case when code is deployed ? - no, i think not. You can log exact time when function is called and by what thread.
3. when you have high load or several threads checking if they should execute then I think you will experience **time dilation**.

Just because you set it to run at 1ms intervals does not mean, that browser does this. For example if i set it to 0 to force it to take smallest possible interval and do this several times to get average i find it smallest interval i could use is ~6 ms. In case of heavy load this increases significantly.

```js
var start = new Date();
var i = 0, interval = setInterval(function(){
    if (++i >= 1000) {
        var end = new Date();
        var result = (end-start)/1000;
        $('#result').text("The average interval was "
                          +result+" milliseconds");
        $('#browser').text(navigator.userAgent);
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 0);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id=result>Please wait about 10 to 20 seconds ...</p>
<p id=browser></p>
```

### How it is really done

It does not count as writing it yourself, but [annotated underscore source throttle function](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-82) :

> Returns a function, that, when invoked, will only be triggered at most
>   once during a given window of time. Normally, the throttled function
>   will run as much as it can, without ever going more than once per wait
>   duration; but if you’d like to disable the execution on the leading
>   edge, pass {leading: false}. To disable execution on the trailing
>   edge, ditto.

```
  _.throttle = function(func, wait, options) {
    var context, args, result;
    var timeout = null;
    var previous = 0;
    if (!options) options = {};
    var later = function() {
      previous = options.leading === false ? 0 : _.now();
      timeout = null;
      result = func.apply(context, args);
      if (!timeout) context = args = null;
    };
    return function() {
      var now = _.now();
      if (!previous && options.leading === false) previous = now;
      var remaining = wait - (now - previous);
      context = this;
      args = arguments;
      if (remaining <= 0 || remaining > wait) {
        if (timeout) {
          clearTimeout(timeout);
          timeout = null;
        }
        previous = now;
        result = func.apply(context, args);
        if (!timeout) context = args = null;
      } else if (!timeout && options.trailing !== false) {
        timeout = setTimeout(later, remaining);
      }
      return result;
    };
  };
```

From http://underscorejs.org/#throttle

```
throttle_.throttle(function, wait, [options])
```

> Creates and returns a new, throttled version of the passed function,
>   that, when invoked repeatedly, will only actually call the original
>   function at most once per every wait milliseconds. Useful for
>   rate-limiting events that occur faster than you can keep up with.
>
> By default, throttle will execute the function as soon as you call it
>   for the first time, and, if you call it again any number of times
>   during the wait period, as soon as that period is over. If you'd like
>   to disable the leading-edge call, pass {leading: false}, and if you'd
>   like to disable the execution on the trailing-edge, pass  {trailing:
>   false}.

```
var throttled = _.throttle(updatePosition, 100);
$(window).scroll(throttled);
```

Comment: Your answer was very helpful. I was able to solve the problem by removing the setInterval and instead using two new Dates() and calculating an interval that is updated each time it is called.

Answer (score 0):

you need to clear the interval, because they still increment the counter no matter if you set to zero the interval is still working, and if you want to call the other functions, not just one set false calledOnce.

maybe the this code can help you.

---

```
var throttle = function(func, delay) {
  var counter = 0;
  var calledOnce = false;
  var count = function() {
    counter++;
    if(counter > delay) {
      clearInterval(handle);
      handle=0;
    }
  };
  var handle = setInterval(count, 1);
  return function() {
    if (!calledOnce) {
      calledOnce = false;
      counter = 0; 
      return func.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but this function does not work at all. Also, I don't want to clear the interval. I want the counter to continue counting, i just want it to restart from 0. Your function never sets calledOnce to true, and because your if statement only checks if(!calledOnce) it never fails, which means this throttle function never throttles

Comment: I tested it with a large delay time and I was able to call it over and over without any delay

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
var throttle = function (input, delay) {
    var counter = 0;
    var calledOnce = false;
    var prev = Date.now();

    return function () {
        var now = Date.now();
        counter = now - prev;
        if (counter > delay || !calledOnce) {
            calledOnce = true;
            counter = 0;
            prev = now;
            return input.apply(null);
        }
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

One does not need a ton of local variables for a decent throttle function. The purpose of a throttle function is to reduce browser resources, not to apply so much overhead that you are using even more. As proof of evidence of this claim, I have devised a throttle function that has only 3 "hanging" variables in its scope. (A "hanging" variable is a variable that is never garbage collected because it always remains referenced by a function that could *potentially* be called, thereby soaking up memory.) Please observe.

```
var timenow = self.performance?performance.now.bind(performance):Date.now;
function throttle(func, minInterval) {
    var lastTimeWent = -minInterval;
    return function() {
        var newTimeWent = timenow();
        if ((newTimeWent-lastTimeWent) > minInterval) {
            lastTimeWent = newTimeWent;
            return func.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    };
}
```

Testing With Your Example:

```js
(function(){"use strict";
var timenow = self.performance?performance.now.bind(performance):Date.now;
function throttle(func, minInterval) {
    var lastTimeWent = -minInterval;
    return function() {
        var newTimeWent = timenow();
        if ((newTimeWent-lastTimeWent) > minInterval) {
            lastTimeWent = newTimeWent;
            return func.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    };
}
var callBack = function () {
    console.log('\tcalled!');
};
var func = throttle(callBack, 1000);

var start = timenow();
wrapper();                     // should be called
setTimeout(wrapper, 500);      // should not be called
setTimeout(wrapper, 1000);     // should be called
setTimeout(wrapper, 1500);     // should not be called
setTimeout(wrapper, 1900);     // should not be called
async function wrapper(){
    console.log("Calling after " + Math.round(timenow()-start) + "ms...");
    func();
    console.log("Done Calling!");
}
})();
```

By default, this throttles the function to at most one call every 200ms. To change the interval to a different number of milliseconds, then pass a key named "interval" in the options argument and set it to the desired milliseconds.